# Can you use two different shifters (eg. Left-Tiagra,Right-105) on the same cockpit/handlebar?

Tags: shifter, handlebars, tiagra, 105

I couldnt find the correct crankset... so i was wondering if you could use a crankset (Tiagra) with a (105) front derailleur? If not can you use two differnt shifters on one cockpit/handlebar and if its worth it?

Comment: It depends on the specific version of the group sets. Shimano lists compatibility here: [https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-454](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-454)

Comment: Why would you match the shifter with crankset instead of derailleur?

Comment: A Tiagra crank should work with a 105 FD + brifter. if the 105 is 10 speed

Comment: The crankset and shifter do not have to match up as far as groupset name. A 105 shift system (right and left) will work just fine whether the cranks are Ultegra, Tiagra, Tourney, etc. You can even use a front drive from a different speed system with normal results if the front drive is +/-1 speed group. This is certainly so up thru 10 speeds. All this is true given compatibilities elsewhere are adhered to (proper sized FD cage for the large chainring, total capacity not grossly over spec, double FD in use with 2x shifter, triple w/ 3x--yes you can hack this mix, but I prefer not to deal w/ it)

Answer (score 14):

The shifters on your left and right side don’t have to match. They can even be from completely different manufacturers.

On road bikes it can be problematic because when riding “on the hoods” (the riding position you should spend most time in) your hands are resting on the shifters. If the two have a different shape it could introduce an asymmetry to your whole seating position which could lead to all kinds of problems.

Comment: Thanky you very much !

Comment: There was a brief trend in the 90s for drop bars with a downtube shifter for the front mech, a plain brake lever on the left, and a combo shifter/brake lever on the right hand side.  That's about as different as one could get.

Comment: For quite a while in the 90s (and well into the 00s to be honest) my touring bike ran with a bar end lever for the right/rear shifter and a downtube lever for the left/front. I **had** matching bar end levers originally, but the pivot bolt unscrewed and dropped out part way up a long climb and I didn't realise until I got to the top. The chances of finding the bolt were pretty minimal and a friend I was riding with had a spare front downtube lever, so it was off with the cable stop, on with the lever, thread the cable and adjust!

Comment: Many bicycles only have one shifter in these days. Present vs missing is probably more difference than otherwise could be.

Answer (score 2):

Another consideration is how much it might annoy you to have two mis-matched brifters while riding.

I had to ride with one black 105 shifter and one grey RSX shifter for a while due to damage, and at first it didn't bother me.  However it was grating, so after a few months I found a matched set of 105 shifters and the bike looked so much better.

I have a bike with mismatched crank-arms too, but that bothers me not-at-all because you can't see them both at the same time.  Shifters were more obvious, and even though they're mostly under your hands, the visual effect was gnawing, and I found I was riding more after the change.

For some people this will never be an issue, for others it will never be possible.  Where are you in that continuum ?

Comment: +1 for the aesthetic angle. It, too, would drive me bonkers coming up to my bike with two different STI's.  When Jenson sent me two right side top covers for my XT shifters to eliminate the gear displays, I shook my head in disgust every time I got on the bike for the next couple weeks while it got sorted out. This hobby/ lifestyle develops some strange idiosyncracies